# Proving the limit of a function exists at one (and only one) point.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

I'm examining the following function:

$   f:x \mapsto \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      x & x \in \mathbb{Q} \\
      0 & x \in \mathbb{Q}^C\\
\end{array}
\right. $

I've been told that the limit of this function only exists at $0$. I have proved that the limit does, in fact, exist at 0. I seem to be hitting a roadblock with proving that the limit doesn't exist at any other points. I'm frankly unsure how to approach the proof using epsilon-delta. (Edit: How do I prove that $|f(x)-L| > \epsilon$ for any arbitrary L?) Some guidance would be very appreciated.

Comment: Hint. There are irrational numbers arbitrarily close to each rational, and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x_0\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$. Take a sequence $(q_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of rational numbers and a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of irrational numbers such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}q_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x$. Then$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(q_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}q_n=x,$$whereas $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=0$. Therefore, $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)$ does not exist and so $f$ is not continuous at $x_0$.

Comment: I was thinking that the sequence approach might make more sense but wasn't sure what sequence to use. I'll try to think of specific sequences myself. 

Comment: @chrisduds Is there something non-specific in my answer?

Comment: If c is irrational how would you define a sequence of strictly rational numbers converging to it? For example a_n=(1/n) +c converges to c, but wouldn't each term be irrational?

Comment: @chrisduds Yes. For that reason I wouldn't use that sequence. I would use the seqeunce $\left(2^n\left\lfloor\frac c{2^n}\right\rfloor\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ instead.